# What happens after OnPause(), can a listener still be called?

Tags: android, firebase

While waiting for reply from a Firebase `ValueEventListener` I did not want my `Activity`, when going into `OnPause()`, to stop listening with this code:

```
removeUIListener(OnUpdateUserDoneListener.class, this);
```

Can I put that line in the `onStop()` instead of the `OnPause()`? so that when `User` return back and the listener has fired everything will be ok?

Or in another question - what happens after `OnPause()`? Can a listener like this:

```
/**
 * Waiting for all done when updating User
 *
 * @param userItem the user item
 */
@Override
public void OnUpdateUserDone(UserItem userItem) {
    isUpdateUserDone = true;
    if(isCreateToyDone)
        exitSearch();
}
```

still be called?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in general an Activity is just an ordinary Java object. `onCreate(), onPause(), onStop()` etc. are just ordinary Java methods. All magic comes from the system container that runs the activity and calls these methods at a specific moment of [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
So - onPause does not affect the state of activity, but it's called when activity is put in the background.
If you create some listener object, it will exist as long as it has connection with some GC root ex. living activity (even in background) or simply firebase that keeps a reference to this listener.

Generally, if you want to listen for events from the activity in the foreground, you should register listeners in `onResume()` and unregister them in `onPause()`. For reference when specific lifecycle methods are called check above link.